# Mongo query to check whether subobject exist or not

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

I have a collection invoice with subobject address.'invoiceId' is the key of main object(Invoice) and '130704432ST'is key for address(address subobject is saved as Map(key,value) pair).I need to check whether this subobject exists or not, if exist I need to update this. So while querying it gives no object found for below query. I am using spring Mongotemplate query in my application. So my query looks like below.

Kindly share if you find any issues with this query and also help me with Mongo query to execute in Robo 3T 1.2 for below criteria.

```
Query: { "_id" : { "$java" : 144068830 }, "addresses.144068830SF" : { "$exists" : true } }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
```

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "invoiceId" : 130704432
    },   
    "destStoreNbr" : 82,
    "invoiceTypeCd" : "M",    
    "countryCode" : "US",
    "invoiceNumber" : "0000000086       ",    
    "totalAmt" : 1038.76,
    "invoiceId" : 130704432    
    "addresses" : {
        "130704432ST" : {           
            "streetAddress4" : "",
            "name" : "kEN-MART",
            "streetAddress3" : "",
            "invAddrTypeCode" : "ST",
            "streetAddress2" : "",
            "zipCode" : "310310",
            "cityName" : "ATLANTA",
            "countryCode" : "US",            
            "stateCode" : "AL"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly '$java' does here, I'm not into sprngboot mongo, but your find query should look something like this in robo3T :: db.yourCollectionName.find({'_id.invoiceId':144068830, 'addresses.144068830SF' : {$exists: true} }]) &&& also update query for a field should be :: db.InvoiceUpdate.updateOne({'_id.invoiceId':144068830, 'addresses.144068830SF' : {$exists: true} }, {$set :{'addresses.144068830SF.streetAddress4': 'new address'}})

Comment: You query works fine on mongo shell. Share the source where mongoTemplate is used to execute this query